# Python> UltimateListCtrl with listmix.TextEditMixin

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using wx libraries to build my desktop application, I built my UltimateListCtrl and now I'm trying to edit the contents of all cells.

This is the class to create the UltimateListObj:

```
from wx.lib.mixins.listctrl import ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin, ColumnSorterMixin
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl  as  listmix
from wx.lib.agw import ultimatelistctrl as ULC

class ultimateList(ULC.UltimateListCtrl, ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin, ColumnSorterMixin, listmix.TextEditMixin):
def __init__(self, parent):
    ULC.UltimateListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, size=(1040, 100), agwStyle=wx.LC_REPORT | wx.LC_VRULES | wx.LC_HRULES | wx.LC_SINGLE_SEL | wx.LC_EDIT_LABELS)
    ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)
    listmix.TextEditMixin.__init__(self) **<------ THIS IS THE CODE I WOULD LIKE TO WORK**

def GetListCtrl(self):
    return self
```

And here the code where i call this class:

```
self.list_granulari = ultimateList(self)
```

This code doesn't work, how can i modify my ultimateList class?

Comment: Could you expand on "doesn't work"

Comment: I mean this code doesn't let my ultimateslistctrl's cells to be editable, the result that i would like to reach.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve